# Import xcframework into Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, xcframework

Is there a way to import an iOS xcframework into a Xamarin Project? I know there doesn't seem to be a way to import it into a Xamarin Forms project but most Xamarin Forms also have a .iOS project (along with a .Android) in the solution. I wonder if the xcframework can be inported into that project and then access through a dependency service. To this point, I have not gotten anything to work.

Any thoughts or other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like it can, but they don't specify how [Github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/10046)

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/13138) also. They all refer to Xamarin.iOS, which I guess that you could somehow integrate it in your Xamarin.Forms project

Comment: I appears that someone had success build a Xamarin iOS project with an xcframework, though it doesn't go into much detail as to how. Our project is a Xamarin Forms project, not Xamarin iOS, so that process will not work for us.

Comment: You can refer to this link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/627693/xamarin-forms-xcframework.html).